# How to detect and solve android application performance issues?

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, android-bitmap, android-profiler

I'm trying to figure why is my app stutter when a user is switching between activities and when a Dialog is created.

I dump my app performance in order to detect anomalies using Profiler and playing with the app for some time.

[image]

The only abnormality I managed to detect is the relatively huge number of "Native Size" of Bitmap, in comparison to to other objects:

[image]

But I don't really know if its abnormal and if so, how to investigate and solve it.

The app is pretty big so I think it would be best the share the whole repo for you to be able to view the code:

https://github.com/steingolditay/ezBalans

Comment: ...and where is the code? How can we comment or notice you a bug without see any line of code? It seems you create many Bitmap, so start from there...

Comment: I didn't know what part of code is relevant in this case because I don't know what and where is the cause of the issue. Can you guide me on what would be helpful ?

Comment: There are near 180k Bitmaps allocated in memory, so I think you could start from where you load them using some Bitmap or Image methods.....but it's difficult to be more precise without see the Code.

Answer (score 0):

Open the activity which you think is lagging and in the logcat filter byword `Choreographer`, if you find

> Skipped 60 frames!

in the logcat, it means that the application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

then you can optimize your calls and processing for that activity

Comment: I played with the whole app (which mainly consists of 3 activities and some fragments) and I got only 3 Choreographer logs, all skipping below 60 frames, although I see the app ui stutter in real time.

Comment: it should not skip any frames that is the reason of UI stutter

Comment: Just to emphasize...the app skipped frames only 3 times while I moved through screens for about 20-30 seconds. The ui stuttered even when no frames were skipped.

Answer (score 0):

1. I noticed in your memory screenshot there are four leaks detected by the memory profiler. Did you try clicking on the label to see what they are?
2. For debugging missed frames, use the CPU profiler to record a System Trace. See https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler#frame-render. Once you locate red frames (longer than the 60 Hz threshold), look at your render/UI thread for long running trace events that might have contributed to the bottleneck. This [video](https://youtu.be/9kNhB_z704I) may be of help.